# displaying images in a list box so the image resizes based on parent container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, expander

I have an expander with a list box in it that displays image thumbnails.  I want the images to be sized according to the size of the listbox and the list box to be sized based on the width of the expander.  When I expand the expander I want the list box and the images to resize also.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```
   <Expander
            Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle}"
            Name="pictureExpander"
            IsExpanded="True"                
            ExpandDirection="Left"
            Collapsed="pictureExpander_Collapsed"
            Expanded="pictureExpander_Expanded"
            Grid.Column="4">
            <ListBox 
                Name="photoList" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhotoBin}}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image 
                            Source="{Binding FileLocation}"
                            Margin="0,5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            MouseLeftButtonDown="DragImage" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the "Stretch" Property on your image:

```
<Image 
     Source="{Binding FileLocation}"
     Margin="0,5"
     MouseLeftButtonDown="DragImage"
     Stretch="Uniform"
     StretchDirection="Both"/>
```

you can play with the values to get the effect you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretchdirection.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stretchdirection.aspx

Comment: I was able to get it to resize when I manipulate the expander but the problem now is that when the application renders the images are being displayed at their full size.  How would i get it to initially have a width of about 200 pixels?

Comment: hm... I don't think you can have both the resizing and the original width forced. because if you set the original width, it will not longer adapt to the parent's width. Depending on the effect you want to achieve, you might want to play with maxWidth/minWidth on you image and/or the stretchDirection, but I'm not sure you can accomplish this.